# Is it correct to say that a non-Async method that discards a task is at the "top" of an async-await chain?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I understand how an `async` method itself works: The compiler transforms it into code that creates a state machine (on the heap) so that the method is in effect "paused" where it reached the `await` and a `Task` is returned and the call stack unwinds. At the "bottom" of this chain is a method that simply returns a task, typically after kicking off a "naturally asynchronous" process such as I/O.

Then, what is at the "top"? I imagine that the topmost method simply discards the task so it can move on. Is that correct?

Maybe the easiest way someone could describe this is if our execution context is a Windows Forms app and the "top" is the message pump.

Comment: Can you explain us the context of your question? What is your problem that this information will help you solve?

Answer (score 3):

Usually nothing is at the top.  The whole point of the state machine you describe is that when the async action finishes, it performs a *callback* on the state machine's `MoveNext` method (the name being a legacy of the `yield` operator essentially being a primitive precursor to `async` semantics).  This process isn't really callstack based, it's more analogous to an event making a callback to some method of yours (in this case, the compiler-generated `MoveNext` method).

So to answer your question, the async method "finishes".  All the way up the chain, each async method "finishes".  But when the actual async process makes that callback, things resume.  Each async method up the chain will make subsequent callbacks to the previous frame's `MoveNext` method, allowing previous frames in the callstack to "resume".

Consider the following code:

```
static async void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(await A());
}

static async Task<int> A()
{
    return await B();
}

static async Task<int> B() 
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return 1;
}
```

What happens when you execute `Main`?  If this were an ordinary static `Main` method entry point without `async`, this would be a problem as you'd immediately exit the program.  This is one of the reasons for the notion that when you use `async` you need to use it [all the way up the callstack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). With C# 7.1 you can actually provide an `async` entry point.

What happens when `Main` invokes `A`?  `A` immediately invokes `B`.  But `B` awaits a delay.  This is true `async` so the whole callstack unwinds.  But after one millisecond, the state machine for `B` will wrap up, and invoke the continuation state for `A`.  The state machine for `A` will in turn wrap up and invoke the continuation state for `Main`.  Finally, the state machine for `Main`, in possession of the return value of `A`, writes out `1` to the console.